# Get lowest bytes from an uint16_t in C

Tags: c, bit, lsb

I want to get the lowest bytes of an `uint16_t` in C.

Example:

```
20544 = 0x5040
0x40 = 64
```

I tried, `(X & ((1<<2) - 1))`. This doesn't work for me.

Comment: *doesn't work for me.* - why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: your example suggests you want the lowest byte (`0x40`), not the lowest bits.

Comment: Yeah.. looks like you mean "two least significant hex digits". Or your example is incorrect

Comment: Your edit made it even worse. You want *one* byte, and the code is not corresponding at all now.

Comment: updated the question. was a typo.

Comment: `0x5040` is only two bytes long.  If you want the lowest two bytes, the answer is `0x5040`.  ***Do you even know how Hex works??***

Comment: I suggest you to stop editing, think a bit and reword the question and the code completely. No rush.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I didnt post my question correctly. thanks for fixing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use bytes (plural), but a `uint16_t` is composed of two bytes, so I'm assuming you mean the least significant byte (singular).  If that's so, here is one way of obtaining it:

```
uint8_t lsb = ((uint8_t)(((uint32_t)(val)) & 0xFF))
```